# What is the key LFD?

Tags: keystrokes

One of the keys Emacs refers to is the key `LFD`. For example, calc binds that key to `calc-over`. What key is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LFD` refers to "linefeed". This key is similar to return -- in ways not worth discussing here -- but can be input with `C-j`.

Comment: `C-j` is the newline character, aka linefeed, abbreviated nowadays as [`LF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), not `LFD`. See that wikipedia page for the relation between carriage return and linefeed (newline).